# Authorization using Vue.js and Express,js

Tags: express, vue.js, authentication

I have a problem with my Vue.js app. I have an Express backend and a authorization on it and i use passport.js to make it. 
Next i have Vue.js application where should be pages that cant be open if user is not authorized and i want to check it.

I try to use cookies but after some variants i finally confused about it. My browser is saving cookies for my server, and i cant read it on client because "http-only" flag, and i cant check authorization with a get request becase idk (there is no cookies on client?).

So, what is a best way to make it?

Comment: Have you looked into JWT? There should be a solution for you. Place a JW Token in each request (from client to the server), then check the request in express and verify the token, if OK redirect the client to the requested page, else send error

Comment: Specify in the question if you are making a SPA.

Comment: @HelloThere What?? I don't get what you're asking

Comment: Sorry i mean, can i do something with passport or jwt is a only option?

Comment: And yes, i have SPA.

Answer (score 0):

So i add a header in Express like that

```
const allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type, accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

then
check authorization

```
axios.get('url',{withCredentials:true})
```

and login

```
axios.post('login',{withCredentials:true})
```

like that